# Project JEDI issue

Tags: jvcl

I found issue in JvDesktopAlertStack,but cannot create account in https://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/signup_page.php (create but confirm email not received).
How can report this issue?

```
procedure TJvDesktopAlertStack.UpdatePositions
```

ignore `dapMainFormBottomRight,dapMainFormBottomLeft` etc,specifically
on MultiMonitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a look at the email issue, but in the meantime, could you create a test application as a GIST?
Or even better, if you have a suggested fix, create a pull request at github.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/egroups/63b02ef10b12b7ee7f83e648e48097f7 my simply patch

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a starting point to reproduce the issue that only occurs when a secondary window targets the mainform window. A fix has just been pushed to GIT.